# Module not found: slf4j.api

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, java-14

I have error at compile time. I use Spring Boot, JavaFX and those two technologies are integrated by EasyFXML.

When I try run app I get the following error:

```
Error:java: module not found: slf4j.api
```

I use Java 14 with Maven

Below my pom.xml and module-info.java file.

Anyone know how resolve the issue ? I was searching for some solution in the stackoverflow but I didn't find. I added at the end of pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-alpha4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

but this dependency nothing changed.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter- 
    parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from 
    repository -->
    </parent>

<groupId>com.*.*.*</groupId>
<artifactId>*-*-*</artifactId>
<version>***</version>
<name>*****</name>
<description>*****</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <!--            <version>1.4.193</version>-->
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
        <version>8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>moe.tristan</groupId>
        <artifactId>easyfxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-alpha4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

module-info.java file

```
module invoiceApp {
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.graphics;
requires javafx.web;

requires spring.boot;
requires spring.boot.starter.web;
requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
requires spring.beans;
requires spring.context;

requires json;
requires fontawesomefx;
requires spring.security.web;
//    requires spring.security.oauth2;
requires spring.boot.starter.data.jpa;
requires spring.core;
requires spring.data.commons;
requires spring.security.config;
requires spring.data.jpa;
requires spring.jdbc;

requires java.sql;

requires java.persistence;
requires spring.orm;

requires moe.tristan.easyfxml;

requires java.base;
requires java.se;
requires org.slf4j;

opens com.***.invoice.app;
opens com.***.invoice.app.view;
opens com.***.invoice.app.repository;
opens com.***.invoice.app.controller;
opens com.***.invoice.app.config;
opens com.***.invoice.app.service;

}
```

**Updated**

[image: Execution command part 1]
[image: Execution command part 2]
[image: Build with 1 error]

Comment: what does your execution command look like? I don't see `slf4j.api` as a part of your descriptor at least.

Comment: I added images with execution command. I changed one sub-package for privacy reason to "xxx" which is highlitted on red color. What is descriptor ? Can you explain? because I don't understand what is it.

Comment: did you try `requires slf4j.api` in your module-info?

Comment: Yes, I did. When I input slf4j.api in module-info text is highlited on the red color.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need help
Did you try this ? `requires org.slf4j; requires org.slf4j.simple;`
(In my case I was using slf4j.simple)